# merge HTML table base on <td>s text

Tags: jquery, html, css

for example this is my HTML `table`

```
 _____ ______ ______ 
|__a__|__a___|__b___|
|__z__|__t___|__b___|
```

this table is dynamic according to my data i want merge `<td>`s if has same text
for example finally show this for me

```
 ___________________
|_____a______|      |
|  z  |  t   |  b   |
|_____|______|______|
```

**Edited**

i want on both side vertical and horizontal merge this.

Comment: How far did you get and where are you stuck? Show us what you have so far. Also, if the table is dynamic, you mean you want to do this while building it? Or is it there already and you want to modify it? Is it even a table in the DOM tree, or is it a piece of HTML source? And, what if the bottom left cell in your example would have contained "a" as well? You can't have L-shaped table cells.

Comment: provide any solution you tried so far

Comment: Please use below code : <table><tr> <td colspan="2"></td> <td rowspan="2"></td></tr>          <tr> <td></td> <td></td> </tr>  </table>